# Dynamically added form elements are posted to PHP but cannot access them

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I'm posting dynamically added form elements to PHP via AJAX.

I can see that the serialised form data is posted to the php, but when I try to access the data within it, some of the fields come up NULL i.e. var_dump in the PHP below shows NULL.

this is the Jquery that adds the dynamic elements:

```
$(function(){
var count=0;
    $('#more_edu').click(function(){
    count ++;
    $('#education_add').append('<br><br><label>University/Institution: </label><input type="text"  class="searchbox" id="edu_inst'+count+'" name="edu_inst[]" maxlength="200" value="">);
    event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

and the Jquery posting to php:

```
function profileSub(){
var myform;
        event.preventDefault();
        myform = $('form').serialize();

     $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'tutorprofileinput.php',
  data: {"form": myform},

success:function(data, response, xhr){
 console.log(response); 
   console.log(data); 
   console.log(xhr);

  },
  error:function(){
    // failed request; give feedback to user
    $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
  }
});
}
```

This is the original form:

```
<form id="tutor_profile_input" onsubmit="return false;">
<label>University/Institution: </label>
<input type="text"  class="searchbox" id="edu_inst" name="edu_inst[]" maxlength="200" value=""> </br></br>
<label>Subject:</label> 
<input type="text" class="searchbox" id="edu_subj" name="edu_subject[]" maxlength="200" value=""></br></br>
<label> Level  </label>
<select id="edu_level" name="edu_level[]">
```

and the PHP itself:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['form'])){
$form = $_POST['form'];
var_dump($_POST["edu_inst"]);?>
```

This is the var dump of the whole $_POST:

location=&price=&tutorname=&edu_inst%5B%5D=Uni1&edu_subject%5B%5D=subje1&edu_level%5B%5D=BA&edu_inst%5B%5D=uni2&edu_subject%5B%5D=subj2&edu_level%5B%5D=BA&bio=%09&exper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have discovered the answer so thought I would share - The Jquery serialize() function encodes the data into a string, which is then posted to PHP as an array with the key of "form".

In order to deal with this in php I had to first use the urldecode function in PHP to convert the string encoded elements (%5B%5D) from the name attributes. This was because there might be multiple values in these so they were declared in the form as an array ("name="edu_insts[]"). Then use parse_str to split the string into an array.

```
<?php
$querystring = $_POST['form'];
$querystring = urldecode($querystring);
parse_str($querystring, $params);
$insts = $params['edu_inst'];
echo $insts[0]."<br>";
echo $insts[1]."<br>";
?>
```

This will create an array named $params with keys corresponding to the form name attributes.

Note that if you have multiple values within the same name, then each one will be placed within an array itself, so with the above text you will have $insts[0] = University 1
and $insts[1] = University 2 etc.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The form you've posted has an ID of `#tutor_profile_input`, where as the one you're appending to in the jQuery function is `#education_add` - Unless I've misunderstood?

Otherwise I'd look at specifying a more specific target in the AJAX request - You're just targetting `$('form')` at the moment which could be any form on the page..

Comment: Hi christian - thanks for this input! actually there is only one form on the page, so I figured targeting the only one would minimise the chance of errors - though now you mention it - this page will be included into another page with forms so will adjust this for safety. #eduacation_add is a div containing the form elements that relate to education - any other thoughts would be much appreciated - been on this all day

Comment: Looking at the var dump with a fresh pair of eyes, there's `edu_inst%5B%5D=Uni1` and `edu_inst%5B%5D=uni2` - So it looks like the value is coming through to PHP? Presumably Uni1 was the value you entered in the original form, and Uni2 was the value you entered in the field that was appended by the Javascript call, no?

Comment: The jQuery you've got is also missing an end `'` - It should be `maxlength="200" value="">');` not `maxlength="200" value="">);` - Presumably this is just a typo in your above code though, as otherwise the Javascript would be invalid and the field wouldn't be appended.

Comment: - thats correct - Uni1 was the input value for the first and Uni2 for the second - but I cant seem to pick these up in the PHP which is the frustrating thing - I also checked it in a url decoder and %5B%5D correspond to [] which is from the name declaration as an array (which I will need as there are potentially multiple strings with the same name attribute.

Comment: the jquery is just a type as the field is appended no problem

Comment: OK - think am making progress here - I think the problem is that the serialize() function creates a string, and that this would need to be decoded in the PHP - otherwise PHP will not recognise the wierd characters (%5B%5D) send as part of the string - this also explains why the $_POST array only contains 1 item i.e. the single string from the form. will now look at decoding the URL string in php